# How can I use a trained CNN tensorflow model to test an input image from another .py file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I've trained and saved my model successfully (image classifier) using tensorflow so now I have the .meta , index and checkpoint files.

I wanted to feed my model an image for testing so I create another .py file and restored my model :

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model-24900.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,"model-24900")
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

after that I tried to feed an image :

```
    Prediction=sess.run([output],feed_dict={input_img : testImage,})
```

the problem that 'output' and input_img are defined in another file( where I've constructed and trained the model so they are undefined in the file where I want to test the model.

This is how I wrote in my train file:

```
    with tf.name_scope("Input") as scope:
    input_img = tf.placeholder(dtype='float', shape=[None, 128, 128, 1], name="input")

with tf.name_scope("Target") as scope:
    target_labels = tf.placeholder(dtype='float', shape=[None, 2], name="Targets")

nb = NetworkBuilder()

with tf.name_scope("ModelV2") as scope:
    model = input_img
    model = nb.attach_conv_layer(model, 32)
    model = nb.attach_relu_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_conv_layer(model, 32)
    model = nb.attach_relu_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_pooling_layer(model)

    model = nb.attach_conv_layer(model, 64)
    model = nb.attach_relu_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_conv_layer(model, 64)
    model = nb.attach_relu_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_pooling_layer(model)

    model = nb.attach_conv_layer(model, 128)
    model = nb.attach_relu_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_conv_layer(model, 128)
    model = nb.attach_relu_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_pooling_layer(model)

    model = nb.flatten(model)
    model = nb.attach_dense_layer(model, 200)
    model = nb.attach_sigmoid_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_dense_layer(model, 32)
    model = nb.attach_sigmoid_layer(model)
    model = nb.attach_dense_layer(model, 2)
    output = nb.attach_softmax_layer(model)



with tf.name_scope("Optimization") as scope:
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    cost = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model, labels=target_labels)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost)
    tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost,global_step=global_step)

with tf.name_scope('accuracy') as scope:
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output, 1), tf.argmax(target_labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

So my question is how can I define 'output' and 'input_img' (that I've used in train file) in my test file so I can feed an image to my CNN model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] **Testing by `.ckpt` file and recreating the whole model:**

- you can redefine the whole model with input tensors and output tensors that you did during training in the `.py` file that you are using in the training
- Now you need to make a forward pass by giving the test image to the input tensor that you define and get the predictions from the output tensor but no training should be preformed
- The model that you define in the test .py file has to have the same structure that was used in the training

2] **Testing by `.ckpt` file and using the name of the tensors:**

- You can explicitly name tensors in the training
- During testing `.py` file you can easily get the input and output tensor by `.get_tensor_by_name("example:0")` function that you explicitly named during training
- And you can use these tensors in the `sess.run` where you will feed data to the input tensor and get the prediction

3] **Testing by `.pb` frozen graph  and using the name of the tensors:**

- The above two methods are still trainable and the file size of these is larger then the `.pb` file
- `.pb` frozen file is a freeze graph which is not trainable
- You can use this file to import you frozen graph
- Now you can get the input and output tensors by `.get_tensor_by_name("example:0")` function and make predictions

**=========================UPDATED=========================**

There are two ways you can know the name of the tensor:

1] **Using Tensor-Board:**

- Save your model after training
- Open the terminal and run the command tensorboard --logdir="path_where_you_have_stored_ckpt_file"
- open http://0.0.0.0:6006/ into your web browser
- Go to graphs section and identify the name of the tensor by clicking on that particular tensor node

2] **In the code:**

- Every Tensor has name property
- You can do something like this:

  ```
  for node in graph_def.node:
     print(node.name)
  ```
- If you want name of a particular tensor you can do something like this:

  ```
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  print(x.name)
  ```
- Once you have the name you can easily use the name to retrieve the tensor from by using : `.get_tensor_by_name(x.name)`

Comment: How can I know the output tensor's name used in the model ?  in my code 'output' is the last layer,  is it the output tensor ? My problem maybe simple but I couldn't find a solution since it's my first experience with deep learning and tensorflow.

Comment: @SalhiFedi I have included how you can look for tensor name in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it

Comment: @SalhiFedi ... If my answer serves as the solution to your question and it helps you then please don't forget to mark it as correct